# Lock application with knock code using always on top Activity

Tags: android

I am new in Android. I am developing a kind of app locker. I want to start a fullscreen always on top `Activity` that listens to `onTouchEvent()`, when the user starts a locked app. I want to make user to get rid of that `Activity` only if he/she enters a knock code as password. I have used following code to lock buttons by making `Activity` always on top (Source: [Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)). But `onTouchEvent()` does not receives any touches for knock code.
I have searched a lot and tried a lot of codes. But always one solution destroys other parts like current problem!

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT ,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                 PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

                 WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

                 ViewGroup mTopView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_color, null);
                 getWindow().setAttributes(params);
                 wm.addView(mTopView, params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onTouchEvent()` does not work because we have an overlay on top of everything. So when we touch screen, we touch `ViewGroup`. So we need to trigger `onTouchEvent()` when user touches `ViewGroup`. We can trigger it like this:

```
mTopView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) 
            {  
                   // do something ...
            }
});
```